# Email validation Regex JAVA

Tags: java, regex, email

I have a requirement to have email validation using java regex same as I already have on JSP. When I am copying regex from JSP to JAVA, I am getting an error.However, in JSP it is working fine.

```
if (null != email) {
            String regex = "^([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{1,6}))?$";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
            if (!matcher.matches()) {
                addFormException(new DropletException("Email not valid "));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In java regex, you have to use 2 backslashes to escape. Ie, `\\`

```js
if (null != email) {
            String regex = "^([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-zA-Z]{1,6}))?$";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
            if (!matcher.matches()) {
                addFormException(new DropletException("Email not valid "));
            }
        }
```

Comment: It Worked, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are having issue with your regex.Please use below regex expression and try run your code. Your above code has only one slash.

```
 String regex = "^([_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-zA-Z]{1,6}))?$";
```

Comment: This is the correct regex expression. why -1 is given

Comment: I just ran this on regex101 and put in mark@yahoo.com as an example and with your regex it came back as no match. That might be possible reason. But so did the regex in the comment marked as correct.